# -ms-grid-columns is stacking columns

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

This is the CSS my grid is currently using:

```
.projectStatusCountGrid {
    display: grid;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}
```

This is what my grid actually looks like in IE11:

[image: FFFF-]

However, when I inspect it, it reveals that the grid columns are all there... they're just all stacked up in the same place. What do I need to add to fix this that won't affect anything in browsers with modern functionality?

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't know where to put the columns unless you tell it.  That's why they're piled on top of each other.  For each `div` inside your `display: grid` container, specify a column:

```
.projectStatusCountGrid div:nth-of-type(1) {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
}

...

.projectStatusCountGrid div:nth-of-type(12) {
  -ms-grid-column: 12;
}
```

Comment: So if I wanted to use this solution, I'd have to insert a bunch of empty divs, or would this work for dynamically added divs as well?

Comment: I think it would work with dynamically added `div`s because CSS styles are  automatically applied to any element in the DOM that is changed.